# Fast Refresh on commit of materialized view

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I just created tables DEPT and EMP like follow :

```
create table DEPT
( dept_no number , dept_name varchar(32) , dept_desc varchar(32),
  CONSTRAINT dept_pk Primary Key (dept_no) );

create table EMP
( emp_no number, dept_no number, CONSTRAINT emp_pk Primary Key (emp_no,dept_no));

insert into dept values (10,'it','desc1');
insert into dept values (20,'hr','desc2');

insert into emp values (1,10);
insert into emp values (2,20);
```

I created materialized view logs on these tables with rowid and materialized views as follows:

```
create materialized view log on emp with rowid;
create materialized view log on dept with rowid;

create materialized view empdept_mv refresh fast on commit as
select a.rowid dept_rowid, b.rowid emp_rowid, a.dept_no,b.emp_no
from dept a, emp b
where a.dept_no=b.dept_no ;

select * from emp;
    EMP_NO    DEPT_NO
  ---------- ----------
     1         10
     2         20
     3         30

select * from dept;
   DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME                        DEPT_DESC
---------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
    10 it                               desc1
    20 hr                               desc2
    30 it                               desc3

select * from empdept_mv;

DEPT_ROWID         EMP_ROWID             DEPT_NO     EMP_NO
------------------ ------------------ ---------- ----------
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAA AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAA         10          1
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAB AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAB         20          2
```

I inserted a new record and did COMMIT; ..but still when i check the materialized view, the new record is not shown in the materialized view.

```
insert into dept values (30,'it','desc3');
commit;
insert into emp values (3,30);
commit;

select * from empdept_mv;

DEPT_ROWID         EMP_ROWID             DEPT_NO     EMP_NO
------------------ ------------------ ---------- ----------
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAA AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAA         10          1
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAB AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAB         20          2
```

Now, when I run the procedure for Fast and complete refresh as [per](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/refresh.htm#DWHSG8366%20), The Fast refresh does not update the Mview but the complete refresh does. ( Note: **But the Mview is still REFRESH ON COMMIT**)

```
execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('empdept_mv', 'F', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DEPT_ROWID         EMP_ROWID             DEPT_NO     EMP_NO
------------------ ------------------ ---------- ----------
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAA AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAA         10          1
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAB AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAB         20          2


execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('test_mview2', 'C', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DEPT_ROWID         EMP_ROWID             DEPT_NO     EMP_NO
------------------ ------------------ ---------- ----------
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAA AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAA         10          1
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAB AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAB         20          2
AAAli5AABAAAPZ6AAC AAAli7AABAAAQs6AAC         30          3
```

The DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW output is as shown : (capability_name --Possible-- msgtxt)

1. PCT --N--
2. REFRESH_COMPLETE --Y--
3. REFRESH_FAST --Y--
4. REWRITE --N--
5. PCT_TABLE --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and RELATED_TEXT for
   details
6. REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_INSERT --Y--
7. REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ONETAB_DML --Y--
8. REFRESH_FAST_AFTER_ANY_DML --Y--
9. REFRESH_FAST_PCT --N-- PCT is not possible on any of the detail
   tables in the mater
10. REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and
     RELATED_TEXT for details
11. REWRITE_FULL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the
     materialized view
12. REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- materialized view cannot support
     any type of query rewrite
13. REWRITE_PARTIAL_TEXT_MATCH --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the
     materialized view
14. REWRITE_GENERAL --N-- materialized view cannot support any type of
     query rewrite
15. REWRITE_GENERAL --N-- query rewrite is disabled on the materialized
     view
16. REWRITE_PCT --N-- general rewrite is not possible or PCT is not
     possible on an
17. PCT_TABLE_REWRITE --N-- Oracle error: see RELATED_NUM and
     RELATED_TEXT for details

**How can I achieve Fast Refresh On Commit ?**
The Oracle Version details are as follows:
NLSRTL                  10.2.0.4.0  Production
Oracle Database 10g     10.2.0.4.0  64bit Production
PL/SQL              10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux:          10.2.0.4.0  Production

Comment: It works for me.  You might want to add your `create materialized view log...` and your inserts so we can fully reproduce the issue.

Comment: You haven't shown any data, nor stated which table you inserted the row into. Do you see the new row when you run the select statement that defines the MV query?

Comment: I have included all the insert statements. Yes, I am able to see the new row after the insert in the table.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the problem still persists, but as I took a look at the artice you provided, I noticed something (which might just be the solution here):

**ON COMMIT Refresh**

A materialized view can be refreshed automatically using the ON COMMIT method. Therefore, whenever a transaction commits which has updated the tables on which a materialized view is defined, those changes are automatically reflected in the materialized view. The advantage of using this approach is you never have to remember to refresh the materialized view. **The only disadvantage is the time required to complete the commit will be slightly longer because of the extra processing involved.** However, in a data warehouse, this should not be an issue because there is unlikely to be concurrent processes trying to update the same table.

- *Notice the bold line.*

Then we have:

**Table 7-1 ON DEMAND Refresh Methods**

Refresh Option  Parameter   Description
**COMPLETE**        C           **Refreshes by recalculating the defining query** of the materialized view.

**FAST**            F           **Refreshes by incrementally applying changes to the materialized view**. For local materialized views, it chooses the refresh method which is estimated by optimizer to be most efficient. The refresh methods considered are log-based FAST and FAST_PCT.

**FAST_PCT**        P           Refreshes by recomputing the rows in the materialized view affected by changed partitions in the detail tables.

**FORCE**           ?           Attempts a fast refresh. If that is not possible, it does a complete refresh.
For local materialized views, it chooses the refresh method which is estimated by optimizer to be most efficient. The refresh methods considered are log based FAST, FAST_PCT, and COMPLETE.

- *Notice the bold lines.*
- *I personally prefer the FORCE Option.*

Could you please tell, if this occurs again after some time (depending of the parameters of the DB and the machine it runs on, so I can't even hint you how much)?

**When Fast Refresh is Possible**

**Not all materialized views may be fast refreshable.** Therefore, use the package *DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW* to determine what refresh methods are available for a materialized view.

If you are not sure how to make a materialized view fast refreshable, you can use the *DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW* procedure, which provides a script containing the statements required to create a fast refreshable materialized view.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I see that you created the materialized view logs with ROWID, which is not really required as both tables have a primary key so you could try without the ROWID.

create materialized view log on emp;
create materialized view log on dept;

Additionally, if you create the materialized view log with ROWID you should create the materialized view with rowid.

create materialized view empdept_mv refresh fast on commit WITH ROWID as
select a.rowid dept_rowid, b.rowid emp_rowid, a.dept_no,b.emp_no
from dept a, emp b
where a.dept_no=b.dept_no ;

You could try those changes and see if the materialized views fast refresh on commit.